# Arduino gets stuck: battery powered, wireless, dc motor drive

Tags: serial, sensors, current

I have a Arduino Mega 2560 connected to

1. L293D Motor Driver IC connected to two small size dc motors.
2. MPU-9150 using i2c
3. Xbee v1.1 arduino shield by seeed
4. Li-po battery, 7.4 volts, 2200 mah.

All components are tested separately, they all are working fine, the sensor readings showing data on serial monitor, the l293 drives the motors, xbee sends wireless serial data on pc, and li-po is also working fine.

I have checked the wiring alot of times. It all seems to be correct.

The problem arises when i connect all of them together, since I am using a single power source, I power the l293d with the Li-po and the Arduino also with the Li-po.

1. When the L293D is powered using Li-po and it starts drawing current from the battery, the serial monitor/arduino gets stuck. It doesnt show sensor readings anymore, while the dc motors start spinning. And they continue to spin, until I break connection with the battery.
2. Without the l293d powered, the sensor readings are working fine, everything is going normal, as it should, but as soon as the l293d is connected, arduino is stuck..

I have searched alot of forums for this, found some info, perhaps something to do analog and digital ground? mpu-9150 is digital ground. So that is why it stops the arduino mega as the l293d starts drawing current. All hell breaks loose.

Can anybody please help me with this? it is giving me headaches ever since!

Comment: Can you provide a schematic or wiring diagram?

Comment: Did you use decoupling caps or are you challenging the laws of nature?

Comment: Try adding a high value capacitor to the 5V. Alternatively try powering the motors using the battery voltage directly instead of (though the regulator) to  5v. Also, what happens if you only disconnect the motor, and not the L293D?

Comment: @jippie, many of your readers (like me) have a software background, not EE, and may not know what you're talking about with bypass caps. I've seen them used in regulated power supplies. It would be helpful if you provide a link to you would use bypass caps in a circuit that has both power loads and a micro controller on it.

Comment: @DuncanC to be honest, that was more or less the reaction I was hoping for. Check these related questions on EE:http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105820/transistor-rating-with-capacitive-load and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59325/whats-the-use-of-a-decoupling-capacitor-near-a-reservoir-capacitor/59328#59328 and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90971/does-my-circuit-need-decoupling-caps/90972#90972 The problem is clearly related to power surges and caps may be able to solve that. BTW OP should really post a circuit diagram, because details unclear.

Comment: What do you think of my suggestion of powering the Arduino with a 9 volt battery as a test? That should isolate the large current pulses of the load from the Arduino board, and also keep the high frequency noise from the Arduino from getting to the motor driver.

Comment: @DuncanC when done correctly that is a perfect method to identify the cause of the problem, I do not think using two power sources all the time can be considered a good solution.

Comment: @DuncanC i have tried two power sources. 7.4v Lipo for the L293D and 9 Volt battery for the arduino, the ground is common between all, i hope that isnt creating problems?

Comment: @jippie decoupling caps? can u highlight please?

Comment: @Gerben ill show the circuit, where to add the capacitors? 
and it WORKS fine without the motors connected to L293D. as soon as the motors start rotating, no more readings.

Comment: okay newbie here, how to add image?

Comment: Just add the capacitor between 5v and GND. You can't put an image inside a comment. You can however edit you question and add additional info, like an image, to it.

Comment: @Gerben the only 5 Volt source that i have is on the L298N motor driver shield. it is basically a voltage regulator, so the 7.4volt coming from LIPO is regulated to 5Volts. now where to add the capacitor

Comment: @gerben i mean the L298N has a voltage regulator in it, and it powers the L298N by using the voltage regulator, 7.4volt regulated, used to power the motor driver. and the 7.4volt used to drive the motors.
https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=7wcBRF2MZnrUtM&tbnid=wpzRFhWuIOknzM:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fitm%2FArduino-Motor-Controller-Shield-L298N-Drive-2-Motors-%2F330521096218&ei=aR3UU5L0L6Sa0QWso4DgDQ&bvm=bv.71778758,d.d2k&psig=AFQjCNEBkuBsnJB0eLBP-aiHp5TO4xN8Cg&ust=1406496486061746

Comment: the link given is of the motor shield

Comment: Just put it on the arduino's 5v and GND. Aternatively add it to the battery's + and -.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your motors are drawing too much current and the voltage from your battery is dropping too low for the voltage regulator on the Arduino. Looking at the data sheet, the L293D will provide up to 600-mA for up to 2 motors at a time. That's up to 1.2 amps, a whole lot of current. I would suggest trying to power your arduino from a separate 9 volt battery as an experiment.

Comment: i tried having two power sources.

Comment: 1. Lipo 7.4v for the L293D
2. 9 Volt battery for the Arduino.

there is a ground common between all, i hope that isnt creating the problems?